# Layout repeats on device but looks fine on emulator when adding image in a Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

let me try to explain clearly with what I want here. I have a RelativeLayout that contains a header image and the content below it.

Now, when i have a header image and a list view below it, the page fits the screen in the device properly, the layout does not repeat.

But when I place an image below the header image, the layout repeats in the device. Meaning i could see 2 header images in the device. Some page, I could see half of the header image that is not supposed to be there (repeated header image). However, in emulator, all the pages looks fine and fit the screen nicely.

I tried changing to LinearLayout, RelativeLayout inside LinearLayout, Relative Layout, it gave me the same outcome. I hope someone could tell me why this happened.
Thanks.

Attached is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/header"
android:contentDescription="@string/image"
android:src= "@drawable/header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/journal"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/kick"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/image"
android:padding="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/favourite_journal" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/kick"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/journal"
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/image"
android:padding="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/favourite_kick" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/labour"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/journal"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/journal"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/image"
android:padding="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/favourite_labour" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/share"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/kick"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kick"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/image"
android:padding="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/favourite_share" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is a </ScrollView> tag without a matching <ScrollView> tag, is it the problem?

Comment: If the </ScrollView> it is just a typo, then try to add the attribute  android:layout_below="@id/header" to the 'content' layout, that can force the content below the header.

Comment: @ZitengChen adt catches such errors, if the `</ScrollView>` isn't a typo it shouldn't compile.

Comment: @ZitengChen sorry i forgot to remove them when i paste my codes here. nope, that is not the problem. previously i had a scrollview and i put it below the header. but i still encounter the same problem. i thought removing the scrollview will help, but it is the same.

Comment: OK if you want to put the content below the header then you should add the attribute android:layout_below="@id/header" to the content layout, or the content will by default align to the top border of the parent layout and overlap with the header.

Comment: Thank you @Ziteng Chen. I missed that out. Thanks for telling me. However I still encounter that problem after doing so. I managed to solve it by changing the inner relativelayout's layout_width & layout_height to fill parent

Comment: @BobbeHoddi eventhough i sort it out, i would like to ask, how does adjustViewBounds affect the codes? I'm new in Android, and as I understand, it will maintain the aspect ratio. I shall try your method and see if it works

Comment: @BobbeHoddi i tried removing adjustViewBounds in my codes, it helps to solve some other errors that I faced. Thanks! But, I couldn't afford to remove adjustViewBounds in header as the entire image will not fit in the screen according to its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it.
I would have to set the layout_width and layout_height of the inner RelativeLayout to fill_parent.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/header"    
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Thanks @Ziteng Chen for hinting me on the position.

```
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
```

and also @BobbiHoddi for your suggestion to remove adjustViewBounds. It helped in other errors that I encountered for my images.

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```